# Listview Grouping error: <property> not found on 'System.Object[]'

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

**I receive the following Listview Grouping error:**

> Binding: 'Profile' property not found on 'System.Object[]', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

I am attempting to use the following class for [ListView grouping](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/):

```
type RecentLinksAdapter(profileSeed, linksSeed) =
    let mutable profile =     profileSeed
    let mutable recentLinks = linksSeed

    member x.Profile 
        with get()=       profile
        and  set(value) = profile <- value

    member x.RecentLinks
        with get() =      recentLinks
        and  set(value) = recentLinks <- value
```

I then have a [viewmodel](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Mobile/UILogic/Profile/Portal.viewmodel.fs) that references the above type as an ObservableCollection:

```
type ViewModel(dependencies) =

    inherit ViewModelBase()

    ...

    let mutable subscritions = ObservableCollection<RecentLinksAdapter>()

    member x.Subscriptions
             with get() =      subscritions
             and  set(value) = subscritions <- value
                               base.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ x.Subscriptions @>)

member x.Init() =

    let setSubscriptions (result:ProviderRequest list) =
        let adapter = result |> List.map (fun s -> RecentLinksAdapter(s.Profile, s.RecentLinks))
        x.Subscriptions <- ObservableCollection<RecentLinksAdapter>(adapter)

    userId
     |> query.Subscriptions
     |> function
        | Result.Ok    result -> setSubscriptions result
        | Result.Error msg    -> ...
```

Here's the ListView that I'm trying to apply grouping to:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Subscriptions}"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True">

            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Profile, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}" 
                               FontSize="Micro" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                       <Label Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here's the **three** binding errors:

```
[0:] Binding: 'Profile' property not found on 'System.Object[]', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
[0:] Binding: 'Profile' property not found on 'System.Object[]', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
[0:] Binding: 'Profile' property not found on 'System.Object[]', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
```

**Appendix:**

1. The value converter, *NameConverter*, never gets executed.
2. The UI shows three blank fields per subscription item in *Subscriptions*.

[image: Subscriptions is initialized with three items]

[image]

Here's the *Link* definition that's referenced from *RecentLinks*:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Link = { 
    ..
    Title:         string
    ..
}
```

Here's the *Profile* definition:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type ProfileRequest = {
    ...
    FirstName:  string
    LastName:   string
    ...
}
```

Comment: Every time you update the Subscriptions property, you are changing subscritions to a new ObservableCollection object. I haven't used this approach to UIs, but I'm pretty sure that isn't right.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.groupdisplaybinding?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ListView_GroupDisplayBinding) it looks like the ItemsSource has to point to an IEnumerable of ObservableCollection<T>'s. It seems you need to implement a group-type that itself is ObservableColelction<T>.

Comment: @Matiasd You're suggestion works. Thank you.